Persistent Notification Not Updating When App is Closed, Incorrect Prayer Time Name, and Missing 45-Minute Reminder in Android App
I’m working on an Android app that displays prayer times and sends notifications at specific intervals. However, I'm facing a few critical issues with the notification system, particularly when the app is closed or in the background. Here are the main issues:
Persistent Notification Not Updating When App is Closed: The app displays a persistent notification showing the countdown to the next prayer time. This works fine when the app is open or running in the background, but when the app is completely closed, the countdown in the notification stops updating.
Incorrect Prayer Time Name in Notification: When a prayer time arrives, the notification sometimes displays the incorrect name of the prayer. For example, if it’s time for Dhuhr, it might display Asr instead. This inconsistency makes it difficult for users to rely on the notification.
Continuous Notifications at Prayer Time: At the exact prayer time, instead of sending a single notification, the app sometimes sends multiple notifications in quick succession, which leads to a poor user experience.
Missing 45-Minute Reminder Notification: The app is supposed to send a reminder notification 45 minutes before each prayer time. However, this reminder is not being sent, even though the code seems to be set up to handle this.
Code Structure:
I'm using a ForegroundService for the persistent notification and an AlarmManager to restart the service periodically if it stops.
For scheduling tasks, I’ve also attempted using WorkManager to trigger updates every 15 minutes when the app is closed.
I also have a BroadcastReceiver and a separate worker for handling prayer time notifications and reminders.
Goal: I want to achieve a reliable notification system that:
Continuously updates the countdown in the persistent notification, even when the app is fully closed.
Displays the correct prayer time name at the time of each prayer.
Sends only a single notification at each prayer time.
Sends a reminder notification 45 minutes before each prayer time.
Any guidance or examples on how to resolve these issues would be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance!
private fun startTimer(nextPrayerTime: Long) {
        // Eğer runnable daha önce başlatılmadıysa, başlatılır
        if (!::runnable.isInitialized) {
            runnable = object : Runnable {
                override fun run() {
                    val currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis()
                    val timeRemaining = nextPrayerTime - currentTime

                    if (timeRemaining > 0) {
                        val hours = (timeRemaining / (1000 * 60 * 60)).toInt()
                        val minutes = ((timeRemaining % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60)).toInt()
                        val seconds = (timeRemaining / 1000 % 60).toInt()

                        binding.timerTextView.text = String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", hours, minutes, seconds)
                        notificationHelper.showPersistentNextPrayerTime(currentPrayerName ?: "Namaz", timeRemaining)

                        handler.postDelayed(this, 1000)
                    } else {
                        if (currentPrayerName != null && isPrayerTimeReached(nextPrayerTime)
                            && (lastSentPrayerName != currentPrayerName || lastSentPrayerTime != nextPrayerTime)
                        ) {
                            notificationHelper.sendPrayerNotification(currentPrayerName ?: "Namaz")
                            Snackbar.make(binding.root, "${currentPrayerName} vakti geldi!", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show()

                            lastSentPrayerName = currentPrayerName
                            lastSentPrayerTime = nextPrayerTime
                        }

                        fetchLocationAndPrayerTimes()
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        // Yeni timer başlatılmadan önce mevcut runnable durdurulur
        handler.removeCallbacks(runnable)
        handler.post(runnable)
    }



package com.example.esmaulhusna

import android.app.AlarmManager
import android.app.NotificationChannel
import android.app.NotificationManager
import android.app.PendingIntent
import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.net.Uri
import android.util.Log
import androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat


class NotificationHelper(private val context: Context) {

    private val notificationManager = context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
    private val notificationId = 1001

    init {
        createNotificationChannel()
    }

    // Bildirim kanalı oluşturma
    private fun createNotificationChannel() {
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            val channel = NotificationChannel(
                "PRAYER_NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL",
                "Namaz Bildirimleri",
                NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH
            ).apply {
                description = "Namaz vakti bildirimleri"
            }
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel)
        }
    }

    // Kalıcı bildirim oluşturma fonksiyonu
    fun createPersistentNotification(prayerName: String, contentText: String): android.app.Notification {
        val intent = Intent(context, MainActivity::class.java)
        val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT or PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE)

        return NotificationCompat.Builder(context, "PRAYER_NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL")
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification)
            .setContentTitle("Bir sonraki ezan: $prayerName")
            .setContentText(contentText)
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_LOW)
            .setOngoing(true)
            .setSilent(true)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setShowWhen(false)
            .build()
    }

    // Kalıcı bildirimi güncelleme fonksiyonu
    fun updatePersistentNotification(prayerName: String, formattedTime: String) {
        val intent = Intent(context, MainActivity::class.java)
        val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT or PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE)

        val notification = NotificationCompat.Builder(context, "PRAYER_NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL")
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification)
            .setContentTitle("Bir sonraki ezan: $prayerName")
            .setContentText("Kalan süre: $formattedTime")
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_LOW)
            .setOngoing(true)
            .setSilent(true)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setShowWhen(false)
            .build()

        notificationManager.notify(notificationId, notification)
    }

    // Namaz bildirimi gönderme
    fun sendPrayerNotification(prayerName: String) {
        val sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("NotificationPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
        val lastSentPrayer = sharedPreferences.getString("lastSentPrayerName", "")

        // Aynı vakit için birden fazla bildirim gönderilmesini önlemek için kontrol
        if (lastSentPrayer == prayerName) {
            Log.d("NotificationHelper", "$prayerName bildirimi zaten gönderildi.")
            return
        }

        // Kullanıcının seçtiği veya varsayılan ezan sesi URI'si
        val selectedSoundFileName = sharedPreferences.getString("ezanSound", "ezan_sesi_1")
        val soundUri = Uri.parse("android.resource://${context.packageName}/raw/$selectedSoundFileName")

        val intent = Intent(context, MainActivity::class.java)
        val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT or PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE)

        val notification = NotificationCompat.Builder(context, "PRAYER_NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL")
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification)
            .setContentTitle("$prayerName vakti geldi!")
            .setContentText("Lütfen hazırlanın.")
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(soundUri) // Seçilen ezan sesi burada kullanılıyor
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .build()

        notificationManager.notify(notificationId + 2, notification)

        // Son gönderilen namaz vaktini kaydet
        with(sharedPreferences.edit()) {
            putString("lastSentPrayerName", prayerName)
            apply()
        }
        Log.d("NotificationHelper", "$prayerName vakti bildirimi gönderildi. Kullanılan ses: $selectedSoundFileName")
    }

    // 45 dakika öncesi bildirim fonksiyonu
    fun sendPriorNotification() {
        val sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("NotificationPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
        val hasSentPriorNotification = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("hasSentPriorNotification", false)

        if (!hasSentPriorNotification) {
            val intent = Intent(context, MainActivity::class.java)
            val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT or PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE)
            val notification = NotificationCompat.Builder(context, "PRAYER_NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL")
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification)
                .setContentTitle("Namaz vaktine 45 dakika kaldı")
                .setContentText("Hazırlıklarınızı yapın.")
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .build()

            notificationManager.notify(notificationId + 1, notification)

            with(sharedPreferences.edit()) {
                putBoolean("hasSentPriorNotification", true)
                apply()
            }
        } else {
            Log.d("NotificationHelper", "45 dakika kala bildirim zaten gönderildi.")
        }
    }

    // Zamanlayıcı fonksiyonu - 45 dakika önce ve tam vakitte bildirimler için
    fun schedulePrayerNotifications(nextPrayerTime: Long) {
        val alarmManager = context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE) as AlarmManager

        // 45 dakika önceki zamanı hesapla
        val priorTime = nextPrayerTime - (45 * 60 * 1000)
        val currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis()

        if (currentTime < priorTime) {
            // 45 dakika önce bildirim için Alarm
            val priorIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 1, Intent(context, PrayerBroadcastReceiver::class.java).apply {
                action = "PRIOR_NOTIFICATION"
            }, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT or PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE)
            alarmManager.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, priorTime, priorIntent)

            Log.d("NotificationHelper", "45 dakika kala bildirim ayarlandı: Zaman - $priorTime")
        } else {
            Log.d("NotificationHelper", "45 dakika kala bildirim zamanı geçti, bildirim ayarlanmadı.")
        }

        if (currentTime < nextPrayerTime) {
            // Ezan vakti için Alarm
            val prayerIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 2, Intent(context, PrayerBroadcastReceiver::class.java).apply {
                action = "PRAYER_NOTIFICATION"
            }, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT or PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE)
            alarmManager.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, nextPrayerTime, prayerIntent)

            Log.d("NotificationHelper", "Namaz vakti bildirimi ayarlandı: Zaman - $nextPrayerTime")
        } else {
            Log.d("NotificationHelper", "Namaz vakti bildirimi zamanı geçti, bildirim ayarlanmadı.")
        }
    }

    // Zaman formatlama fonksiyonu
    private fun formatTime(timeRemaining: Long): String {
        val hours = (timeRemaining / (1000 * 60 * 60)).toInt()
        val minutes = ((timeRemaining % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60)).toInt()
        return String.format("%02d saat, %02d dakika", hours, minutes)
    }

    // showPersistentNextPrayerTime fonksiyonu - kalıcı bildirimi gösterme ve güncelleme
    fun showPersistentNextPrayerTime(prayerName: String, timeRemaining: Long) {
        val formattedTime = formatTime(timeRemaining)
        updatePersistentNotification(prayerName, formattedTime)
    }
}

